# how append nsdata

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsdata

how i could append nsdata, i would append lenght data on first message to send on socket
i use code like this but error on runing.

```
int lendata = [message length];
NSData *firstdata = [NSData dataWithBytes: &lendata length: sizeof(lendata)];
NSData *mdata = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableData *seconddata = [NSData dataWithData:mdata];
[firstdata appendData:secondata];
```

please tell if there is another way
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Henrik P. Hessel: Most likely an error that `NSData` doesn't respond to `appendData:`.

Answer (score 19):

Glancing into my crystal ball:

1. You are declaring `seconddata` as an `NSMutableData` instance, but then you initialize it using `[NSData dataWithData:]` instead of `[NSMutableData dataWithData:`], so `seconddata` won't be mutable in the end and you cannot append to it.
2. You are trying to append to `firstdata`, which is not mutable either.

Solution: make `firstdata` mutable:

```
NSMutableData *firstdata = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes: &lendata
                                                 length: sizeof(lendata)];
[firstData appendData:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Then you can safely drop `mdata` and `seconddata` as they are not needed anymore.

Comment: thanks Tamas it is work, but i still have problem, my nsstring data is 42 character len, i want add hexa a2 (42 dec) data on first data but output is a2 00 00 00 XX XX XX until 42 character, XX is correct but why a2 have 00 00 00 ? which my code is wrong?

Comment: Integers are stored in four bytes on your system, therefore ``[NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&lendata length:sizeof(lendata)]`` stores four bytes. This is expected. If you want to store just one byte, use ``unsigned char`` as the type for ``lendata``, and make sure that your string is never longer than 255 characters.

Comment: By the way, you are going to get into trouble if your message contains characters that are encoded by more than one byte in UTF-8 encoding. I would first convert the message into an ``NSData`` (e.g., ``NSData* msgdata = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]``), and then use the length of ``msgdata`` instead of the length of the string.

Answer (score 7):

```
 NSMutableData *first_data = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.firstURL];
 NSMutableData *second_data = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.secondURL];
 [first_data appendData:second_data];
 [first_data writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
```

check above code for append

Comment: Please edit your answer and format your code: just select it and then press the `{}` button to have it indented with four spaces (that's our markup for "code").